# Matlab Vectorization using Multiple Columns from an Array

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize a bit of Matlab code that requires input from two adjacent members of an array.  Essentially:

```
x=1:10;
for i=1:9
    y(i) = x(i)+x(i+1);
end
```

Is there a way to vectorize this code so that I don't need to use the for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do I understand this right? Is this what you need?

```
y = x(1:n-1) + x(2:n);
```

?

Comment: I tried that earlier, but I guess I must have made a typo, because that seems to work.  Thanks a ton!